# How to copy MS Windows symlink files as is?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, symbolic-link, mklink

I made some symlinks in MS Windows using `mklink /D` command.
But when  copy it, Windows Explorer always perform deep copy instead copying symlink itself.
How can I just copy the link? I need to send these links to other users on other machine.

Comment: I've downvoted the OP to reconsider the correct answer again, and because there are other answers on SU.

Comment: @M.A. I deselected the answer and I cannot chose one now as I cannot test answers below anymore. Let's see which one to be chosen by community!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 7 / Symlinks - How do I copy a Symlink to a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/148099/windows-7-symlinks-how-do-i-copy-a-symlink-to-a-directory)

Answer (score 4):

partially duplicate question, multiple good answers are [here](https://superuser.com/questions/148099/windows-7-symlinks-how-do-i-copy-a-symlink-to-a-directory)

Using Windows tool

> `xcopy /b /i <source symlink name> <destination symlink name>`

and you should disregard a message:

> output is 0 File(s) copied

also another tool in standard Windows installation: robocopy

> /SL :: copy symbolic links versus the target.

Since you mentioned you want to "send" it, you might get [TAR](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) which can pack/unpack symlinks into one archive file. 7z might one day too.
As I see it, 7zip can archive them but not extract on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

A tool answer: LinkShellExtension allows you to do this and much more. If you're working with soft/hard links in Windows at all, it's an enormously helpful tool.

In this case, you probably want to choose its ['Splice' behaviour in copying Symlinks](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#outerjunctionhandling).

Comment: For other readers, complete instructions can be found here (tested and confirmed working): https://superuser.com/a/1509670/231129

Answer (score 2):

The symlink to a directory acts as a directory itself. So, when you copy the directory, you copy the directory.

If you had a directory with a bunch of files in it and you wanted a copy of it, but without the files in it, you'd just make a new directory with the same name. Same thing applies here, really.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is as simple as that: You cannot. Instead, run the same command on the other machine.

Comment: This is wrong as indicated [here](https://superuser.com/a/148105/297281)

Comment: This is not the correct answer, and I downvote

Comment: This is correct in the context of using Windows Explorer, as mentioned by OP. Indeed, it seems to be impossible with the Windows Explorer GUI. With command-line, it is possible with `xcopy` as mentioned by @AntonKrouglov.

Answer (score -2):

Just drag and drop the symlinks between one explorer window to their destination in another.  It will move them without copy the contents.

Comment: Not working for relative folder symlinks.