# Administrator getting "access denied" - unable to create directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, permissions, xcopy

As far as I can tell, I am in the Administrators group on Windows 7 Service Pack 1. [image: verified this way]

With CMD prompt pinned to my Start menu, I rightmouse and select **Run as Admin** and get this error on **xcopy**:

```
C:\>xcopy "C:\Users\TRA\My Documents" J:\MyDocuments1-TRA /E /I /Y /M
Access denied
Unable to create directory - J:\MyDocuments1-TRA
0 File(s) copied
```

Using Windows Explorer, I can navigate to both the C drive and the J drive (an external HD)
and create New Folders and within them create new files and save content inside the file. I think the syntax on XCOPY is correct.

I am a little uncertain about wrapping the first parameter in double quotes (think that is correct). The main mystery is why access denied. Thanks.

**EDIT - UPDATE:** *More info about external drive, etc.*

There is no domain - just Windows 7 - connection to "J" drive is USB. I can dig out more info on SATA or whatever if needed. Home network only. No domain controller. I did this:

```
C:\>net use
New connections will be remembered.
There are no entries in the list.
C:\>

C:\>dir /al
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 366C-7FCC
 Directory of C:\
 07/14/2009  01:08 AM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           1 Dir(s)  622,991,994,880 bytes free
C:\>j:
J:\>dir /al
 Volume in drive J is SignatureMini
 Volume Serial Number is 18E1-4B50
 Directory of J:\
 File Not Found
```

**UPDATE**: *"the Big Picture" - my objective here:*

I'm just trying to get a "backup" command to run once per day and copy new and/or modified files. I got this XCOPY command in a scheduled task on another Windows 7 PC working nicely. I have had mysterious problems using Windows 7 Backup facility (I guess because this is Home Premium edition and my research suggests this is not supported). Thanks for your time folks. I will press on and appreciate your suggestions/ideas.

Comment: Wrapping in quotes is correct since `My Documents` has a space in it. You could also wrap `J:\MyDocuments1-TRA` in quotes, but since there is no space, it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Domain or local account?

Comment: How is J: connected?  You mention it's an external drive - is it mapped via the network?  USB? eSata?  Something else?

Comment: What file system is on J:?  That is, is it one that supports long names?  Otherwise, your command syntax looks correct, assuming that the directory doesn't already exist on J:.  Also try creating a foldername that doesn't use "MyDocuments", i.e. perhaps "DOCS-TRA".

Comment: BTW, you don't need to do that "run as admin", unless you set ownership on J: to just that account (which seems unlikely since you said you can create files/folders on it in Explorer.)  Try to just run CMD.EXE, then type J: to go to the drive, then MD "testlongdirname" and see if you can create that from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in an admin prompt, you have to remap the drive.  You can see that you don't have a J: in your admin prompt by typing `net use` (it'll say unavailable in the first column of output).

Compare that to the `net use` output from a standard prompt, where you'll have "OK" in the first column.

I haven't tried this, but this [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) suggest you can have the map work by modifying the registry:

```
1. Click Start, type regedit in the Start programs and files box, and then press ENTER.

2. Locate and then right-click the registry subkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System.

3. Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

4. Type EnableLinkedConnections, and then press ENTER.

5. Right-click EnableLinkedConnections, and then click Modify.

6. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.

7. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.
```

Comment: the poster said J: was an external drive, not a network mapped drive. That seems to me like a USB hard disk, pendrive or similar. Maybe he could give us further explanations.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Ack, missed that detail . . . good catch . . . maybe I'll get lucky and it's a NAS that he/she's referring to as an external drive ;)

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez...thank you..please see update above.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from dealing with **junctions** and/or **symlinks**: directories that are not such, but some link, like in the Unix `ln` command.
You can see junctions by typing:

```
dir /al
```

Different copy-programs deal with junctions/symlinks with different behaviors, for what I know.
I propose you two possibilities:

- Install something like [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) that is designed to work with all this stuff. According to its documentation, it adds command-line shell extensions too.
- Use normal directories(folders). Do not use symlinks/junctions for your data if possible (I hate them). You could make a mess when copying data. Even the awesome [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) doesn't copy/duplicate by default all the contents/structure of directories. I know this seems hard, but it is a lot safer. Symlinks(junctions could be needed for the working of Windows structure, but don't rely on them for your data storage.

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/148099/windows-7-symlinks-how-do-i-copy-a-symlink-to-a-directory) shows an example of the complexity when copying data if there are symlinks/junctions involved.