# moving symlinks to another drive

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, cross-reference

i have a list of `symlink`s to commonly used files by me in a directory located on my flash drive `h:\` referencing to files in `c:\` drive

i want to move the contents of my `h:\` drive into `c:\`, and when i do so `symlink`s cause original files on the system to get moved

i don't want to use `shortcut`s for that purpose, i just want to move `symlink`s instead of the original files they refer to from one drive to another

there's no problem when moving them inside the `h:\` drive, but when i move them to another drive they follow the original files

i want to know the cause of this strange for me behavior, that is, why they get moved properly in the same drive, and not when i move them to another drive, and to find a solution for that purpose

Comment: See [*Windows 7 / Symlinks - How do I copy a Symlink to a directory?*](https://superuser.com/a/744510/358766)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found a worthy [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/148099/windows-7-symlinks-how-do-i-copy-a-symlink-to-a-directory) to my question, it's about copying not moving, but there's no problem deleting the source after the copying process is completed to imitate migration :)

it's about using `/b` switch of cli copying tool `xcopy.exe` to:

> copy the symbolic link itself versus the target of the link