# Copying Cygwin symlinks through Windows Explorer won't make them working

Tags: windows, cygwin, symbolic-link

Given two paths with the same content:

```
D:\dir1\file1
D:\dir1\symlink1-to-file1

D:\dir2\file1
D:\dir2\symlink1-to-file1
```

If I create `D:\dir2\symlink1-to-file1` by windows-copying it from `D:\dir1\symlink1-to-file1`, the link won't work and the `file` command will output :

```
D:\dir2\symlink1-to-file1: data
```

Why ?

Comment: Because that's not how symlinks work.

Comment: Ah? I believed Cygwin's links were just binary files for Windows (although they are marked as "system" files).

Comment: Please read [Enable native NTFS symbolic links for Cygwin](//stackoverflow.com/q/18654162)

Comment: Question looks wrong as there's no such thing as a cygwin symlink, and an answer says " it happens with symlinks created with cmd /C mklink too not only cygwin". So indeed, there is no such thing as what you think there is.  "symlink" would not be "cygwin specific".

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for the link (almost three years later).

Comment: @barlop, this old question gets suddendly an unexpected attention. Thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug in Cygwin but in copy/paste function of the Windows Explorer

- moving the folder will keep the symlink as is
- copy/paste the symlink will destroy the symlink

and it happens with symlinks created with `cmd /C mklink` too not only cygwin

few solutions exist for this:
[Windows 7 / Symlinks - How do I copy a Symlink to a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/148099/windows-7-symlinks-how-do-i-copy-a-symlink-to-a-directory/1509670#1509670)

## Gui solution:

1. Download [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html)
2. Run "C:\Program Files\LinkShellExtension\LSEConfig.exe" and change
   the "Outer Junction/Symbolic Link" setting to "Splice".

[image]

3. Right-click the folder you want to copy and click "Pick Link Source"
4. To paste the folder click "Drop As: Smart Copy" , or mirror.

## CLI solution:

I found only two solutions that works:

### ln - command line hardlinks

this is not the `ln` you know in cygwin but other thing, made by the same creator of `Link Shell Extension`, download it from [here](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html)

```
ln.exe --splice --backup --mirror source_dir  destination_dir
```

### strarc

[link](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/), this was made by the same creator of the well known ImDisk, and is suggested by most of people

> strarc may be used to copy a complete directory tree from one NTFS
> volume to another, including all special attributes of NTFS such as
> security information, permissions, ownership, auditing settings etc.

Say you have a directory called `C:\dir` and you want to copy it to `D:\dirbk`. Because strarc as default archives to stdout and extracts from stdin you can type as follows:

```
strarc -cjd:C:\dir | strarc -xd:D:\dirbk -w:8
```

> NTFS in Windows 2000 and later has an option to create "reparse
> points" of empty directories. The implementation involves a "reparse
> data block" which specifies which filesystem filter should handle the
> reparse point and some parameters to the filter about what the
> specific reparse point should do. Windows 2000 natively supports e.g.
> "junction" and "remote storage" type reparse points. The "junction"
> type is actually a link to another native path, very much like a
> symbolic link to a directory path on Unix filesystems. Volume mount
> point directories use this method to make the mount point directory
> actually redirect to the target filesystem. When backing up a
> filesystem with reparse point you have two options. Without special
> switches strarc follows the reparse points as a normal application
> would do. That could be what you want in many cases, but if the
> directory tree you are archiving have e.g. junctions pointing to
> directories above the junction in the tree (making an infinitely deep
> directory tree) or junctions pointing to other filesystems etc you may
> want to backup the reparse points themselves instead of the
> directories they are pointing to. To select the second method, use the
> -j switch to strarc.

---

### rsync

the well known rsync in cygwin is not a solution, because it changes symlinks to a different thing, read about how symlinks work in cygwin in this nice [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654162/enable-native-ntfs-symbolic-links-for-cygwin?rq=1)

### Robocopy

Robocopy is used normally for this and suggested by a lot of articles, but few people know that robocopy is full of bugs and should not be used:

- **serious** robocopy bug (robocopy vulnerable to symlink attack) [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e5a13ff-1dc0-4a34-9e99-37540c0fff60/serious-robocopy-bug-robocopy-vulnerable-to-symlink-attack?forum=w8itprogeneral)
- robocopy doesn't create symlinks when using /sl and /b together, when
  invoked again it will copy at least a file's flags again [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/56e50aba-6cce-42f6-adc4-736c8a0d43a9/robocopy-doesnt-create-symlinks-when-using-sl-and-b-together-when-invoked-again-it-will-copy-at?forum=winserver8gen)
- Robocopy corrupting deduplicated volume [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/1331)

*Who would have thought that such a simple thing like copy a folder needed all this...*

Comment: Thanks for the quite complete answer! It's awful how much is needed to do that indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Check file attribute with CMD command `attrib`

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks

> if the default plain file symlink type is lacking its DOS SYSTEM bit,
>   or if the shortcut file is lacking the DOS READONLY attribute, they
>   are not recognized as symlink.

Comment: Thanks you! I had to choose one answer and took the most complete one, but yours is interesting too. :)