# Windows 10: Move folders that contains directory symbolic links across partitions

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

Suppose I have a folder under partition D that is D:\folder\link_folder which is a directory symbolic link whose target is E:\real_folder, i.e. it was created by:

```
mklink /d D:\folder\link_folder E:\real_folder
```

Now I need to move D:\folder to F:\ by the Explorer UI like cut/paste. But I found that now there is a full copy of E:\real_folder under F:\folder\link_folder which is not a link anymore.

Is there a way to just create F:\folder\link_folder as a link to E:\real_folder during the folder move process? There is a lot of such links under D:\folder.

Comment: How did you try, with Explorer or with Some Commander? Perhaps you could try doing it from WSL: unix products do know the concept of symlinks.

Comment: Why can’t you delete the symbolic link, move the files, then recreate the symbolic link?

Comment: @Ramhound There are a lot of symbolic links. Want a command/flag that can just move the symbolic link which is as expected by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `robocopy` to move folders that contain directory symbolic links by using the `/move` `/SL` and `/e` parameters. Following your example, you could then use the command as follows:

```
robocopy D:\folder F:\folder /move /e /SL
```

`/move` will move the target instead of copy.

`/e` will copy (move) all sub-directories **including empty ones**.

`/SL` will copy (move) the symbolic link instead of following it.

note: *elevated* command prompt is required for moving symbolic links in windows 10.

note: For symbolic links created using `mklink /d`.

References: [Microsoft Docs robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) contains syntax and details on robocopy, examples can be found at [Technet robocopy examples](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx). Related forum post on [copying directory symlinks in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/148099/windows-7-symlinks-how-do-i-copy-a-symlink-to-a-directory).

Comment: The strange thing is that if I don't do this with a administrator command window it will say like "client doesn't have the privilege, waiting for 30 seconds", even I'm testing your solution with newly created simple folders. I don't want to use administrator command windows since this may somehow polute the moved files's ownerships etc.

Comment: Maybe you can check this question too: https://superuser.com/questions/1476047/windows-10-move-folder-across-partition-get-dead-lock-on-symbolic-links

Comment: You can use the`/copy:`parameter to specify what file properties to copy (move). By default, it uses`/copy:DAT`(Data, Attributes, Timestamp), you can add the O flag to copy and thus preserve the ownership, so it would be`/copy:DATO`. The [Microsoft Docs Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) page has description for the various flags for`/copy:`and the corresponding file properties in case there are other access controls you need to to move with the file.

Comment: What about why it reports the previlege error even I test the command on some newly created folders?

Comment: My apologies, it appears that post windows 10 creator's update, enabling developer mode first will then allow moving/creating symlinks without elevated privileges. Otherwise you will still need elevated privileges. I'll update the answer.